# Counting paths to winning distribution

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, combinatorics, graph-theory, vector-spaces

In a tournament, there are $2n$ teams, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Each round, the teams pair up. This means that after each round, $n$ teams win and $n$ teams lose. If we are given a scorecard containing each team’s number of wins after $r$ rounds, we would like to determine all possible ways that this win outcome could have occurred. In essence, we would like to find all possible ways of representing a vector $(w_0, w_1, … w_{2n - 1}), w_i \in \mathbb{N_0}$ as a sum of vectors of the form $(r_0, r_1, … r_{2n-1}), r \in \{0, 1\}$ where $\sum_{i=0}^{2n-1} r_i = n$. How might I go about achieving this?

We tried representing each component of the vector as a node on a graph having a certain value. We were also interested in barycentric coordinates or other coordinate systems. I also tried more of a pure linear algebra approach and represented it as a system of linear diophantine equations, yet we still haven't been able to solve this one.

Comment: To clarify: if teams $1,2$ win and teams $3,4$ lose in a given round, you don't care if this happened because $1$ beat $3$ while $2$ beat $4$, or because $1$ beat $4$ while $2$ beat $3$, right?

Comment: Correct @MishaLavrov